# How to log upstream IP in Apache HTTP server?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm using Apache Http server as a reverse proxy. I am interested in logging the upstream server IP in access and error logs. I'm looking for something like `upstream_addr` of Nginx web server.

Comment: Do you mean the downstream address? Upstream is toward your web application, downstream is toward the user agent.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have figured out how to capture Client IPs. I want to capture upstream web app IP.

Comment: I looked through the [log format strings](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) and I don't see anything appropriate offhand. You probably should be using something else as a reverse proxy anyway. nginx as a reverse proxy can log this, for instance.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah, there was no option out of the box. The reason for logging upstream IP is to identify stale DNS entries. But I am curious to know  why you did you mention that I should look elsewhere _anyway_.